# Web Site Geographic Redundancy

Tags: redundancy

I am planning a fairly large web deployment with geo-redundancy capability.
This is not just clustering a number of servers in a same server room. Some points to consider

1. Load sharing among multiple sites
2. Traffic distribution based on user geographic location (e.g. west coast users only access servers in west coast, etc.)
3. Traffic (automatic) fail-over and fall back in case a total site black-out

Data replication is another topic. I need to sort out the redundancy at the web tier first.
I am considering DNS roundrobin. However the 3rd points cannot be fully fulfilled.
Any better suggestion? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that, unless you have plenty of money to throw around and implement your own, you should contact one of the [content distribution networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network#Commercial_CDNs) that have the infrastructure already in place to do such things.

To have real redundancy is not cheap nor easy to guarantee, there are many points of failure you have to address.

Comment: Generally, CDNs do not allow for dynamic websites or sometimes even static ones. OP is very likely talking about distributing a full dynamic website including services, etc.